# Replace text in word file in all sub folders

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I am putting together a VBA macro that:

1.reads a folder

2.creates a collection of all its subfolders

3.loops through all the subfolders and find any word document ending in .doc

4.in each .doc file: replace a bit of text and save then close the documents.

This macro doesn't work correctly: it doesn't replace the text in any word documents in the subfolders.
It doesn't actual open  any word document, I am unsure wether it should open each word doc one after another or if it runs in the background.

```
Sub DoLangesNow()
Dim file
Dim path As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strSubFolder As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim colSubFolders As New Collection
Dim varItem As Variant

 ' Parent folder including trailing backslash
 'YOU MUST EDIT THIS.
     strFolder = "G:\2009\09771\Design\ESD\Commercial Tower KSD1\Green Star As Built\Round 1 Submission - Draft\02. Indoor Environment Quality"

     ' Loop through the subfolders and fill Collection object
     strSubFolder = Dir(strFolder & "*", vbDirectory)
     Do While Not strSubFolder = ""
         Select Case strSubFolder
             Case ".", ".."
                 ' Current folder or parent folder - ignore
             Case Else
                 ' Add to collection
                 colSubFolders.Add Item:=strSubFolder, Key:=strSubFolder
         End Select
         ' On to the next one
         strSubFolder = Dir
     Loop
     ' Loop through the collection
     For Each varItem In colSubFolders
         ' Loop through word docs in subfolder
         'YOU MUST EDIT THIS if you want to change the files extension
         strFile = Dir(strFolder & varItem & "*.doc")
         Do While strFile <> ""
         Set file = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & _
                 varItem & "\" & strFile)

' Start of macro 1replace text GS-XXXAB  with GS-1624AB
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Application.WindowState = wdWindowStateNormal
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "GS-XXXAB "
        .Replacement.Text = "GS-1624AB "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
' End of macro 1
' Saves the file
ActiveDocument.Save
ActiveDocument.Close
' set file to next in Dir
strFile = Dir
         Loop
     Next varItem
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me with below changes

- From

```
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & varItem & "*.doc")
```

To

```
  strFile = Dir(strFolder & varItem & "\" & "*.doc")
```

- Make sure the path for folder is correct in `strFolder` Variable. Eg( `strFolder = "C:\Users\Santosh\Desktop\tes\`")