# Replace text in documents in subfolders vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I found this thread with the same issue as mine, but I've copied the code into my project, and it doesn't seem to work.

[VBA macro: replace text in word file in all sub folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908344/vba-macro-replace-text-in-word-file-in-all-sub-folders)

I was stepping through the code, and it gets to line 32 (under the For Each varItem in colSubFolders) but then it skips right over the find/replace section to the end of the code. Is the problem in my file format?

EDIT: Additionally, when I get to varitem in ln 31, the value of "varitem" is the name of the folder, not the names of the word documents in the folder: I think this is where the issue is.

```
Sub DoLangesNow()
Dim file
Dim path As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strSubFolder As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim colSubFolders As New Collection
Dim varItem As Variant

 ' Parent folder including trailing backslash
 'YOU MUST EDIT THIS.
     strFolder = "L:\Admin\Corporate Books\2015\2014 Consents macro\company Annual Consents"
     ' Loop through the subfolders and fill Collection object
     strSubFolder = Dir(strFolder & "*", vbDirectory)
     Do While Not strSubFolder = ""
         Select Case strSubFolder
             Case ".", ".."
                 ' Current folder or parent folder - ignore
             Case Else
                 ' Add to collection
                 colSubFolders.Add Item:=strSubFolder, Key:=strSubFolder
         End Select
         ' On to the next one
         strSubFolder = Dir
     Loop
     ' Loop through the collection
     For Each varItem In colSubFolders
         ' Loop through word docs in subfolder
         'YOU MUST EDIT THIS if you want to change the files extension
         strFile = Dir(strFolder & varItem & "\" & "*.doc")
         Do While strFile <> ""
         Set file = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & _
                 varItem & "\" & strFile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CMD to get all the files into an array and work with that instead - quicker and cleaner.

```
Sub S_O()

Dim fileArray As Variant

fileArray = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR """ & strFolder & "\*.doc*"" /S /B /A:-D").StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".")

For Each fil In fileArray
    '//
    '// Insert your code for doing the replacements here
    '// e.g. Workbooks.Open(fil)
    '// ...
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @S O that's got some stuff I've never used... I'm still learning VBA. Could you explain a little more about how I would incorporate that?

Comment: the top line creates an array of all `.doc*` file names in all folders/subfolders of the path given by `strFolder`. You can then loop through this array (using the `For Each` syntax and run whatever code you need against that file, e.g. `Documents.Open(fil)`

Comment: so this puts all of the documents within the selection of subfolders into the Immediate bin? should I clear this at the end of the program? with something like this maybe?

Dim x As Long


For x = 1 To 10    
Debug.Print x
Next

Debug.Print Now

Application.SendKeys "^g ^a {DEL}"

Comment: I've just used `Debug.Print` for demo purposes, you would replace that line with the actual code that you plan on running for each file.

Comment: Oh! That makes much more sense. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I'm not sure why, but my With Selection.Find isn't finding stuff within the files anymore once it's placed into the code there. Do I need to add some sort of command to make it look within the document?

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like - I'd post it as a separate question and post all of the code you are using.

Comment: ah of course... Can I tag you there? Sorry to take your time, you're just the first really helpful commenter on this problem I've had haha

Comment: Don't think you can tag people, but if you use the `VBA` tag it should show up in my feed.